# Aggregate functions in a recursive CTE to calculate fractions of sub-groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

I have a self-referential table which I am designing to describe mixtures of ingredients

| id | raw_input | parent_input | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | x |  | 4 |
| a | y |  | 6 |
| b | j |  | 1 |
| b | k |  | 3 |
| c |  | a | 6 |
| c |  | b | 1 |
| d |  | c | 1 |
| d |  | a | 1 |

I'd like to write a recursive CTE query which calculates the fraction of each base_input in each individual mix. For example, I'd like the output:

| id | raw_input | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | x | 0.4 |
| a | y | 0.6 |
| b | j | 0.25 |
| b | k | 0.75 |
| c | x | 0.34285714 |
| c | y | 0.51428571 |
| c | j | 0.03571429 |
| c | k | 0.10714286 |

- I haven't added mixture d here as it's quite tricky to calculate at this stage

where the values are calculated as such:

| id | raw_input | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | x | `4/(4+6)` |
| a | y | `6/(4+6)` |
| b | j | `1/4` |
| b | k | `3/4` |
| c | x | `0.4*(6/(6+1))` |
| c | y | `0.6*(6/(6+1))` |
| c | j | `0.25*(1/(6+1))` |
| c | k | `0.75*(1/(6+1))` |

My method for attempting this was to join a aggregate total onto the tables in the CTE, then divide the masses by this as such:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, base_input, mass_fraction FROM
        (SELECT E.id, E.base_input, E.amount/f.total_mass AS mass_fraction
        FROM mix_table E
        JOIN (SELECT id, SUM(amount) as total_mass
             FROM mix_table
             GROUP BY id
             ) AS root_totals
        ON root_totals.id = E.id
        WHERE E.base_input IS NOT NULL) AS r
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT b.id, base_input, mass_fraction/totals.total_mass FROM 
        (SELECT F.id, cte.base_input, cte.amount/branch_totals.total_mass AS mass_fraction
         FROM mix_table F 
         JOIN cte on F.parent_input = cte.id) as b
         JOIN (SELECT id, SUM(amount) as total_mass
              FROM mix_table
              GROUP BY id 
         ) AS branch_totals
         ON branch_totals.id = totals.id
    )

select * from cte
```

Running it without the totals joined onto the CTE gets most of the way there, just the individual components of the mixture group C are not scaled by their respective fractions.

It seems like a CTE with an aggregate function is exactly what I want to do, just the error raised by SQL server prevents me doing it.

There must be a way around this, I'm sure I'm not the first person to want to do this.

Edit: I'd like to clarify that I'm aiming to do this for more than one level, where I can expand the solution to account for an indeterminate level of nested parent/children

Comment: Do you need recursion here? Your sample only has 2 levels; the parent and the child.

Comment: Where is 2 coming from in 4th row "b-k-2/4" ?

Comment: @Larnu I was hoping to have a recursive parent-child relationship where the child can also be a parent ad infinitum. and to be able to trace back all cases to the roots

Comment: Then you should really demonstrate that in the question, @dsbbsd9 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my own quandry, and for future viewers I think this only works because it doesn't require the aggregation to be run more than once, I can do the aggregation calculation before the CTE, then use it within the CTE:

```
-- I first define the total aggregation here

WITH totals AS (SELECT id, SUM(amount) as total_mass
              FROM test_mix
              GROUP BY id),
cte AS (
    SELECT id, raw_input, amount FROM
        (SELECT E.id, E.raw_input, E.amount/totals.total_mass AS amount
        FROM test_mix E
        JOIN totals
        ON totals.id = E.id
        WHERE E.raw_input IS NOT NULL) AS r
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT b.id, raw_input, child_q*(parent_q/totals.total_mass) FROM 
        (SELECT F.id, cte.raw_input, cte.amount AS parent_q, F.amount AS child_q
         FROM test_mix F 
         JOIN cte on F.parent_input = cte.id) as b
         JOIN totals                                   -- then use it here
         ON totals.id = b.id
    )

SELECT id,raw_input, SUM(amount)
FROM cte
GROUP BY id,raw_input
```

Answer (score 0):

As you only have 2 levels, it would seem easier to do the `UNION ALL` outside of the CTE, rather than within it:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES('a','x',NULL,4),
            ('a','y',NULL,6),
            ('b','j',NULL,1),
            ('b','k',NULL,3),
            ('c',NULL,'a',6),
            ('c',NULL,'b',1))V(id,raw_input,parent_input, amount);
GO
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT id,
           raw_input,
           amount,
           parent_input,
           (amount*1.) / SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS amountperc
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT)
SELECT id,
       raw_input,
       --amount,
       amountperc AS amount
FROM CTE
WHERE parent_input IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT C.id,
       P.raw_input,
       C.amountperc * P.amountperc
FROM CTE P
     JOIN CTE C ON P.id = C.parent_input;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Sorry @Larnu, I'm not sure I made the example descriptive enough in the question. Would this work if there were more than two levels? for example if I mixed C with A to create mixture D?

Comment: Not as written, no.